# How to redo Content lost on a page in OneNote

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2013

I accidentally deleted a paragraph on one of the pages in One Note 2013. The problem is I don't have the redo button.So I need a way to get it back without using the Redo Button.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the Redo from the Customise Quick Access Toolbar dropdown menu!

1. Click on the arrow icon to the right of the top menu, or choose File > Options >  Quick Access Toolbar
2. Choose the Redo command

[image]